# Unable to use mouse input and keyboard input inside Game

Tags: java, automation

I am planning to simuate the mouse and keyboard actions. I am able to simulate it on windows and all windows applications but when I open the game (Digimon Masters Online) keyboard and mouse simulations stopped working and the script is still running. Can someone tell how they determine whether it is a simulated key press or it is clicked by a human on keyboard. I want to simulate key press and mouse movements like a human do on keyboard and mouse.

Please find the below sample which I have written which is working on all windows applications but not inside the game.

```
Robot r = new Robot();

    while(true)
    {

        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b = a.getLocation();
        int x = (int) b.getX();
        int y = (int) b.getY();
        System.out.print(y);
        System.out.print(x);
        //r.mouseMove(x, y - 50);
        /*r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        Thread.sleep(1000);*/
/*      r.mouseMove(500,500);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        r.mouseMove(700,700);
        Thread.sleep(5000);*/
        r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        System.out.println(r.getPixelColor(x, y));
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }
```

I am able to read color and mouse pointer positions but can't simulate the key press and mouse movement.

Answer (score 0):

DMO requires virtual drivers to move the mouse in-game.
Have you installed the virtual drivers?

General tab > Settings > Input > Install Virtual Drivers
Now you can select Virtual Drivers for Keyboard and Mouse input